# auto updated column by another column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Employee and Sales.
in the Employee table there is a column called 'number of sales'.
 but I want it to be uninsertable.
 so you cannot insert anything to it, and it will be updated by another factor:
for every column in the Sales that has the same ID as that employee I want to see the number of sales in the Employee 'number of sales' column.

something like [number of sales]=select count(*) from sales s group by employeeID where EmployeeID=s.EmployeeID

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to this is a trigger (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)).

You can also use a generated column with a user-defined function.

However, I would caution you from both these approaches because they can be complex and can affect performance in unexpected ways.  Instead, why not just create a view?

```
create view v_employees as
    select e.*, s.cnt
    from employees e outer apply
         (select count(*) as cnt
          from sales s 
          where s.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
         ) s;
```

You can query the view and get the value whenever you need it.  The value is automatically "updated" when the values in `sales` change -- due to inserts, updates, and deletes.